# test if a file has been updated within the current day

Tags: time-date

As I consume a lot of drugs, I created an org-mode file that updates the status of my stock every day.
It is done at the start of Emacs and it slows down significantly.
As I sometimes run Emacs on a single day, I would like a test to see if the file has been updated in the current day.

```
(defun file-updated-today-p (file) .....)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that compares today's date with the last modification date of FILE. If both strings are equal, return t.

```el
(defun file-updated-today-p (file)
  (string= (format-time-string "%F")
           (format-time-string "%F" (nth 6 (file-attributes file)))))
```